# ios app crash when input file Choose Existing selected

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash

I try to use uiwebview for my project. All feature works fine, but when in the application click on the Choose Existing button after selection of input file, app crashed. The error message I get is:

> [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Should I add some function into project to ignore this?

Comment: Share the code, what you did so far?

Comment: Also provide the exception message and indicate which line of code it crashed on

Comment: Please provide more details on this. It's difficult to figure out what is your problem.

Comment: [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to the app the permission to use the photo library.

Click on the project file in the project navigator, and then select "Info" tab. You will see items like "bundle display name" and "bundle version string". Go to the last item and tap the "+" sign there to add a new item.

When a new item has been added, change its name and select "Privacy - photo library usage description", and add some text regarding why your app wants to select a photo (you could leave this blank in older iOS SDKs but not any more).

Now if you run the app again, the app will display the message that you entered and ask for permission to access the photo library. This will happen only once.